# 19.10 lock screen not working, logout works fine

Tags: gnome, 19.10, lock-screen

I'm on a laptop with Intel integrated graphics and an Nvidia 1060, Ubuntu 19.10, gnome desktop.

The screen lock functionality is completely lost; When I press the lock button from shell or `super + L` the screen just goes blank for a second, killing all my open apps and then reopening my desktop as if it is logging out and back in. I suspect this because I have an extension which greets me when I log in and I've also added a vpn to start-up which gets re-enabled when I try to lock.

However, the lock screen (the screen where it asks for password) itself exists and works fine when I log out or reboot.

These are what I've done so far:

- The problem is not existent in a new user account.
- I have tried setting `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen` to `'false'` but it affects nothing.
- I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to no avail.
- I've used `dconf-editor` to look into the settings for abnormalities, found none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; buggy extension, disable one by one and test.

It was caused by a bug in an extension's disable method. Turns out all extensions get disable before system is locked, and `prime indicator` extension had a difficult time figuring out how to let it go.

Disabling all extension solved the problem, which is basically what happened in the new account. So, I checked them one by one.